# Помогите прояснить термины. Многопоточность, конкурентность, т.д

Tags: многопоточность

Смотрел видео и читал статьи, но непонятки остались, правильно ли я все понял. поправьте меня пожалуйста, если я не прав.

Синхронность - поток блокируется на время, пока выполняется задача, ожидая её выполнения.

Асинхронность - поток не блокируется, начиная задачу, и передавая коллбек. Тут же переключается обратно на другие задачи. Когда отрабатывает коллбэк - снова берется за начатую ранее задачу.

Многопоточность - неважно, сколько ядер у процессора, важно то, что задача будет исполняться на нескольких потоках.

Если ядро одно, то это будет конкурентность. Конкурентность, это когда потоки "конкурируют" за время работы процессора и он постоянно переключает их, чтобы каждый из потоков по очереди делал свою задачу. Время отведённое каждому потоку на выполнение не обязательно равное.
Потоки НЕ выполняются одновременно.

Если ядер у машины несколько - тогда помимо конкурентности доступен параллелизм - можно одновременно исполнять несколько задач, каждой задаче по потоку, например.

Есть также микс конкурентности и параллелизма, т.е. когда на нескольких ядрах по несколько потоков, и каждый из потоков на своём ядре работает с другим потоком на своем же ядре конкурентно.

Получается и конкурентность и параллелизм можно назвать многопоточностью.

Также слышал, что то, что я назвал "Параллелизмом" - это называется параллельным исполнением, а параллелизм - разбиение большой задачи на маленькие подзадачи, каждая из которых выполняется на своём потоке.

Comment: Да в целом всё верно, только конкурентность не обязательно означает многопоточность. Конкурентность — возможность многозадачности, когда различные задачи конкурируют за ресурсы и выполняются одновременно (может быть реализована даже в однопоточной системе). Как вариант — планировщик задач или event loop.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. А что насчёт параллелизма и параллельного исполнения?

Comment: В чём вопрос, в терминологии? Параллелизм — разделение задачи на подзадачи, которые выполняются независимо и одновременно для ускорения процесса исполнения. Параллельное исполнение — это непосредственно реализация параллелизма на потоках и ядрах.

Comment: Да, именно это и хотел узнать, благодарю за помощь.

Comment: imho использование слова **"конкурентность"**  в нашем интернете -- это обычно неверный перевод слова *concurrency*, которое должно переводиться как *параллелизм*. Конечно, доля здравого смысла в таком переводе есть, поскольку параллельно выполняемые фрагменты кода вполне могут конкурировать за доступ к ресурсам

Comment: @avp Я тоже раньше придерживался этой точки зрения, но оказалось, что в некоторых ЯП это не совсем одно и тоже. В `Golang`, например, ситуация с этими терминами близка к описанной в вопросе. Тут вот есть прямо картинка со словами `concurrency` и `parallelism`: https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC-%D0%B2-golang-go-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-82bae0f92e81

Comment: Правда @avp в том, что программирование должно быть на английском. Когда работал в Германии, жутко болел с *Dateibearbeitungsprogramme* и прочих слов. Зачем вообще всё это переводить на местные языки…

Comment: @DiMithras У немецкого есть свой шарм. До сих пор помню, что принтер по-немецки Drucker ))